# How to get cell style by name in Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, cell

Am using 3.16

I create some cell styles in a method. And I pass on the workbook to another method for setting cell values.

In this scenario, I have to pass all my cell styles as params to other method. Is there a way I pass only workbook and get styles from that workbook itself.

I found

```
workbook.getCellStyleAt(idx).
```

But for this, i have to keep indexed track of all styles i created. And hardcode it value. if i code for a new style in between then I may mess up the sheet format as the index numbers will change.

sample code

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(1000);
SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("SheetName");

CellStyle styleBOM = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font fontBOM = workbook.createFont();
fontBOM.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);
fontBOM.setFontName("Arial");
fontBOM.setBold(false);
styleBOM.setFont(fontBOM);

CellStyle headKey = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font fontKey = workbook.createFont();
fontKey.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
fontKey.setFontName("Arial");
fontKey.setBold(true);
headKey.setFont(fontKey);

CellStyle headValue = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font fontValue = workbook.createFont();
fontValue.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
fontValue.setFontName("Arial");
fontValue.setBold(false);
headValue.setFont(fontValue);

valueList=someLogicToFetchValues(someInput);

downloadExcel(valueList, workbook,styleBOM, headKey,headValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a static table with all created styles, each identified by its name (or whatever you choose).
Every time you create a style, you add it to that table and when you need it, you read it from that same table.
Something like this:

```
class CellStyleMap
{
  public static synchronized void addStyle(String    identifier,
                                           CellStyle style)
  {
    styles.put(identifier, style);
  }

  public static synchronized CellStyle getStyle(String identifier)
  {
    return (styles.get(identifier));
  }

  private static Hashtable<String, CellStyle> styles = new Hashtable<String, CellStyle>();

} // class CellStyleMap
```

Within your code:

```
CellStyle styleBOM = workbook.createCellStyle();
...
CellStyleMap.addStyle("BOM", styleBOM);
```

And when you need it:

```
CellStyle styleBOM;
styleBOM = CellStyleMap.getStyle("BOM");
```